# mysql fee calculation

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a few tables and columns. I would like to populate table1 with data based on the calculation of data in table2, table3, and table4. I need data in all those tables in order to properly assess what should be inserted into table1. I would like it to be a stored entity so it can be reused over and over by just calling it. What is the best and smartest way to go about this using mysql?
If I'm not being clear enough let me know.
Thankz loads in advance.

Comment: SELECT, INSERT, AND UPDATE statements. Nothing else can be said without knowing your table structures

Comment: you can simply get the data by `JOIN`ing table2,table3,table4 with table1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a stored procedure, and populate table1 with the `insert..select` pattern:

```
Insert into table1
Select column1, column2, column3, ...
From table2
join table3 on ??
join table4 on ??
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use a "view" which is like a table that automatically stays up to date based on a query of joining the other tables. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html